# working and ordering txt file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with Python and a txt file.

I have a txt file as follows:

`w2w9w8b7w4w6b4w7b6w7b4w9w2w8b3w4w3w5w4w7b5w3b6w5b6w6b5b6w1w3b7w6w9w7w2w4w1w3b3w7w2w8w6w5b1w9w8w6b2w3b8w5b5w2w8b4w7w9b3w3w2w1w6w6w2b4w1w7w4b4w9w3b8w4w1b3w5b1w9w8b1`

What I need is for the file to be sorted first in rows and columns of 9x9 as follows:

```
w2 w9 w8 b7 w4 w6 b4 w7 b6 
w7 b4 w9 w2 w8 b3 w4 w3 w5 
w4 w7 b5 w3 b6 w5 b6 w6 b5 
b6 w1 w3 b7 w6 w9 w7 w2 w4 
w1 w3 b3 w7 w2 w8 w6 w5 b1 
w9 w8 w6 b2 w3 b8 w5 b5 w2 
w8 b4 w7 w9 b3 w3 w2 w1 w6 
w6 w2 b4 w1 w7 w4 b4 w9 w3 
b8 w4 w1 b3 w5 b1 w9 w8 b1
```

In addition to ordering in that way, I need that if the number is next to a "w" be kept, and if it is next to a "b" to be removed. The final output would look like this:

```
2 9 8   4 6   7     
7   9 2 8   4 3 5 
4 7   3   5   6  
1 3   7 2 8 6 5  
9 8 6   3   5   2 
8   7 9   3 2 1 6 
6 2   1 7 4   9 3 
  4 1   5   9 8
```

Read the txt file in quite simple, they indicate it in several tutorials, I have already done that. But I have trouble doing the rest.

I'm new to python and I don't have much idea how to work with txt files.

Could you help me or give me any suggestions on how you could implement this? Thank you!!

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question and welcome to Stack Overflow.

There are many ways to skin a cat, so I'll try explain a possible method of doing this for you. I won't write the code for you, but I'll give you an algorithm you could use. I'd encourage you to try sit with problems like these for a bit longer in future, as it's not something you really should need to ask on StackOverflow. This sounds quite like a homework assignment. Nonetheless:

1. Read in the file as a string.
2. Iterate through the string, two letters at a time, and add them as an element into an array conditionally. What this means is, before you insert them into your array, if you detect the element you are adding begins with a `b`, insert the number the element ends with, else insert an empty space, `' '`. Continue until you have reached the end of the string.
3. Iterate through the array you have just created, and add each 9 elements into a new array WITHIN a new array . You now have a 2D array that looks like:

```
[
  ['2', '9', '8' ... ' '],
  ['7', ... '5'],
  ...
]
```

4. It's fairly trivial to print this out in the format you require after this. You can simply iterate through the 2D array and join the elements with an empty space, and then print those out in a loop.

I have described a fairly simple and brutish method for solving this - I am sure you can find many ways of improving its performance.

Good luck!